# Leaflet javascript - get nearest mapped coordinate

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I guess i don't need to have my own list of cordinates like:
New york: 40°42′46″N 74°00′21″  <-- from wiki
....

If I click on map into New york or near it I would like to get upper coordinate.Or if I would click closer to Boston, coordinates of that.

That is, talking on big scale. In reality, any nearest already mapped named spot.

Can I get that direct from leaflet ?